# Monitor the amount of data a process writes to SSD/HDD

Tags: windows, ssd, monitoring

I want to monitor how much data which process writes to my SSD. Is anyone aware of a software for that? [Hard Disk Sentinel](http://www.hdsentinel.com/) monitors how much data is written to a HDD/SSD, but only in total. I am interested in the data written by a process, not the total by all processes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to do this. In the filters set a Process Name filter to the name of the process you are interested in, set a Operation filter to contain WRITE, and a Result filter to SUCCESS. Now, as long as Process Monitor is running, it will record writes done by the process you told it to log.

When you have collected your data go to Tools > File Summary and it will give you a summary of all the file system activity it has logged. Since you told it to only log writes for a process the summary will be a summary of just the writes done by that process.

Comment: I really start to like Process Monitor, however the problem is, that I don't want to know, what a specific process does, but that I want to monitor all processes. Using Process Monitor it seems like I can only see how much was written to which file, but I need a view from process to the amount of data written, not from files to amount of data written to them.

Comment: I haven't found a way to do that with just Process Monitor. When I investigated writes to my SSD ( http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=697061 ) I ended up exporting the log from Process Monitor and adding the number up in another program.

Comment: Which program/script did you use? can you publish it? would be interesting :-)

Comment: I used Mathematica and the results are at the link I gave.

Comment: Any chance you will describe the processes using mathematica in detail? would be an interesting forum topic ;-)

Comment: It was really nothing fancy. Just import the data, use stringsplit to get at the number and then add them up and put the results in a barchart.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [SsdReady](http://www.ssdready.com/ssdready/) as easy to use tool.

Comment: Looks interesting, but reading the description it doesn't sound like it tells one, which porcesses wrote to the files?

Comment: Use button Processes.